# Can I access my garrison before I reach level 90?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So, I resubscribed to World of Warcraft because *reasons*. I haven't played since Cataclysm, so the highest level characters I have are level 85.

If I buy the Warlords expansion, can I access my [garrison](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/garrisons/) right away, or do I need to be level 90 first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be level 90 before you can access your garrison or any of the other Warlords of Draenor content.